# getting safe mode on although i turned it off

Tags: php, linux, apache, lamp

did a phpinfo to check which php.ini is being loaded.
then i put safe mode off saved and restarted apache.
i also put php.ini in the directory and used htaccess safemode off.
htaccess safe mode off throws me a 500.

in any case i am not able to disable safemode?!

Answer (score 1):

if you have allowoverride on All you can use a .htaccess with

```
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
```